# Add button to q-select in Vue.js 3

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar

I want to add a button inside q-select after i click on the dropdown menu but it instead it display my button outside next to the dropdown menu button. This is my code :

```
  <q-select
    v-model="visibleColumns"
    multiple
    outlined
    dense
    options-dense
    :display-value="$q.lang.table.columns"
    emit-value
    map-options
    :options="columns"
    option-value="name"
    options-cover
    style="min-width: 150px"
  >
    <template #append>
      <!-- Add Button Inside q-select -->
      <q-btn
        flat
        round
        dense
        icon="add"
        @click=""
      />
    </template>
  </q-select>
```

Comment: Do you want a button for each option of the q-select? It's not really clear

Comment: I want to add one button inside the list  that will display a dialogue the list to add another option

Comment: check the before-options slot to see if that works for you,  cause i am still not sure if that's what you want! <template #before-options></template>

Comment: exactly. that's what i wanted